# Запись двухмерного массива в CSV

Tags: python, csv

Считал csv файл в список списков следующего вида:

```
[['ФИО', 'Вход', 'Объект входа', 'Выход', 'Объект выхода', 'Время присутствия', ''],
['Абрамов С.Н.', '10.12.2016 9:36:50', 'Корпус 37 ВХОД 1 (17-1)', '', '', '0:00', ''],
['Арианна Т.', '10.12.2016 10:59:31', 'М6 Центр. ВХОД-2 (27-3)', '10.12.2016 19:27:26', 'М6 Центр. Выход-1 (27-0)', '8:28', ''],
['Базолин И.В.', '10.12.2016 13:11:00', 'Корпус 37 ВХОД 1 (17-1)', '10.12.2016 13:42:38', 'Корпус 37 Выход 2 (17-2)', '0:32', '']]
```

Однако по-человечески записать это в новый csv файл не выходит - каждый вложенный список в списке opList пишется в одну ячейку. Выглядит это примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код:
Версия `Python 3.5`

```
import csv
opList = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    fRdr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\\n')
    headers = next(fRdr) #need to rec in 1st row
    opList.append(headers)
        for row in range(0,200):
            opList.append(next(fRdr))
with open('out.csv', 'w') as of:
    wRt = csv.writer(of)
    wRt.writerows(opList)
```

Как правильно с помощью используемого модуля произвести запись списка opList в csv?

Comment: я не вижу где вы редактируете/фильтруете строки, поэтому вам следует проще вопрос задать: «как *прочитать* csv файл с `;` разделителем». Если чтение файла работает (посмотрите на `print(opList)`), тогда спросите «как *записать* список в csv-формате, используя `;` разделитель». Когда научитесь читать и писать, тогда можно к фильтрации/редактированию переходить. Укажите вашу версию Питона.

Comment: csv файл с ; читается нормально - я читаю его в список, где каждый элемент это список полей в строке. А вот писать это в новый csv файл не получается

Comment: Так и  задайте более специфичный вопрос: «как сохранить список в csv файл, используя `;` разделитель». Где входной список может быть: `rows = [['a', 'b'], [1,2]]`. Укажите явно желаемый вывод и что вместо этого получается. Вы не указали версию Питона. Всё остальное только отвлекает (можно в конце и текущее содержимое для контекста привести, но сам вопрос и без этого можно задать—цель, чтобы вопрос был так же полезен будущим посетителям).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы записать список списков в csv формате:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> rows = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]
>>> file = io.StringIO()
>>> csv.writer(file).writerows(rows)
>>> file.getvalue()
'a,b\r\n1,2\r\n'
```

`io.StringIO()` используется для отладки, чтобы показать содержимое, записываемое csv модулем. Обратите внимание, что окончания строк в csv `\r\n` вне зависимости от системы. Если вы пишите в файл, то **следует `newline=''` параметр передать в `open()`** как указано в [документации csv модуля](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), чтобы избежать искажения конца строк из-за универсального режима строк.

Если `1,2` не распознаются как разные поля в вашем GUI, то это значит что программа ожидает какой-то другой формат. Либо явно укажите ей входной формат (генерируемый csv модулем), либо узнайте какой формат эта программа ожидает и измените формат, в которым вы сохраняете данные.